# Fill text label of google slides with spreadsheet's data

Tags: google-sheets-api, google-slides-api

First of all, thank you @Tanaike for the answer.

First goal: I have a Google Forms, and I want to program an automatic report on Google Slides.

Then for each question (text format) on Form, I want put this response that will be on Form's spreadsheet in a label text at Google Slides.

It would be a text label for each page on Slides. I have 4 questions on Forms, then the slide should have 4 pages, each page with the answer of each question.

I thougth it was possible just with built-in functions of Spreadsheet. That leads me to second goal:

Create a script on spreadsheet with trigger start "on save". 
This script will take each cell's content and will put on each Google Slides' label text.

Any help will be apreciated!

Comment: I think that your goal cannot be achieve using only the built-in functions of Spreadsheet. So it is required to use the script. For this, can I ask you about your goal? 1. Can I ask you about `text labels` you are thinking? 2. What language do you want to use for the script? 3. How do you want to run the script? 4. If you will use Google Apps Script, where do you want to put the script? 5. Can you update your question by including the detail information of your goal?

Comment: Thank you for updating it. I noticed that your question had been updated just now. Unfortunately, from your updated question, I couldn't see the vision of your goal. This is due to my poor understanding skill. I deeply apologize for this.